# Are question about power transmission okay?

Tags: support

Today I saw a 10 kilovolt cable being dug under ground and I have detailed questions.

For example, I saw the cable mark and googled it and found that the cable features a copper wires shielding - I'd like to know what's the reason to have copper wires shielding in a 10 KV power cable.

Also I saw that the cable was only one wire, so it takes three such cables running together to have a 3-phase power line - three cables will not be extremely parallel, they will follow slightly different paths and so will have slightly different lengths and slightly different resistance. I'd like to know is these cables having slightly different resistance have any impact on power transmission.

Are such questions okay on this site?

Comment: this sounds on-topic to me.

Comment: It's been asked: [Why would a power cable need copper wire shielding?](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/16877/why-would-a-power-cable-need-copper-wire-shielding)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I can see no reason why this kind of question shouldn't be asked.  Electronics are still electronics even at 10KV.  PDNs are still electronic circuits with electronic components (albeit somewhat more meaty).

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't have given it special thought but since you're asking: I don't think it belongs here. It's about electricity, like home wiring, not about electronics, and especially not about electronic design. This isn't useful for any DIY-er, nor for a professional electronic designer. Maybe you should have mentioned a transistor in the question :-)

Comment: If group thinks that EE questions do not belong here, the title "Electical Engineering" should be replaced with something less pretentious.

Comment: Agree with title change. This site is about electronics, recent moderator action indicates it is no longer about the more general electrical engineering topics.